# Units digit when there is a power of power

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do you find the units digit in case of an expression like this

$$ 7^{8^7}
$$

I know how to find the units digit when there is one integer and there is only one power. But how do I find it when the power has a power.

Please provide a descriptive answer.

Comment: The unit digit of a number $a$ is given by $a \pmod{10}$. The last two digits are given by $a \pmod{100}$, last three by $a \pmod{1000}$, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the last digit of a positive integer is the remainder when you divide it by $10$. Perhaps you have noted that $a^b$ and $a^{b+4}$ have the same last digit for any positive integers $a$ and $b$.

The case you have written is perhaps too easy, since the first exponent ($8$) is a multiple of $4$. Then $8^7$ is a multiple of $4$ and $7^{8^7}$ ends with the same digit as $7^4$.

In the general case, you must note also that the remainder when divided by $4$ of the sucesive powers of a number present also this "periodic behaviour". Take for example
$$7^{11^9}$$
We need the remainder of $11^9:4$, but the remainder of $11:4$, $11^2:4$, $11^3:4$, etc is $1$ for even powers and $3$ for odd powers; therefore, $7^{11^9}$ ends in the same digit as $7^3$, that is, $3$.

Comment: So do I need to first find out the unit digit of 8^7 ? That is coming to 2 so is the unit digit 7^2 that is coming to 9.

Comment: So the expression will be basically 7^(one huge number). Mod 4 of that number will be 7^remainder. But I don't get how to simplify calculation of that number

Comment: I get that for 7 there is mod 4 but what the same example instead I had 9^(11^5) ?

Answer (score 1):

HINT :

Note that 
$$7^0=\color{red}{1},7^1=\color{red}{7},7^2=4\color{red}{9},7^3=34\color{red}{3},7^4=240\color{red}{1},\cdots$$
and that 
$$8^7\equiv 0\pmod 4.$$

Answer (score 1):

By Euler-Fermat's theorem, for any $a$ coprime to $10$, $a^{\varphi(10)}\equiv 1\mod 10$ so that for any $n$:
$$a^n\equiv a^{n\bmod\varphi(10)}\mod 10.$$

Now $\varphi(10)=\varphi(2)\varphi(5)=4$, and $8^7\equiv 0\bmod 4$, hence for any $a$
$$a^{8^7}\equiv 1\mod10.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $7^k$ modulo $10$.

You will notice that it enters a repeating pattern: $7,9,3,1,7,9,3,1,7,9,3,1,\dots$

Where $7^k\mod 10 \equiv \begin{cases}7&\text{when}~k\equiv 1\mod 4\\ 9&\text{when}~k\equiv 2\mod 4\\3&\text{when}~k\equiv 3\mod 4\\1&\text{when}~k\equiv 0\mod 4\end{cases}$

Now, consider the exponent in this case.  $8^7$.  Since the pattern of $7^k$ depends on $k\mod 4$, what is $8^7\mod 4$?

Comment: Do I find the unit digit of the successive exponent ?

Comment: Also mod4 isnt applicable for the powers of 9. So what happens then ?

Comment: @Heidi for $9^k$ you will notice that it follows the pattern $9,1,9,1,9,1,\dots$, so you see that $9^{\text{even}}\equiv 1\mod 10$ and $9^{\text{odd}}\equiv 9\mod 10$.  Whatever the base is, you try to find out how frequently the pattern repeats (it will always eventually repeat), and find out how the exponent fits into that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I was just wondering why the ajotatxe's answer below doesn't apply to this case  7^(6^21).

> In the general case, you must note also that the remainder when divided by 4 of the sucesive powers of a number present also this "periodic behaviour". Take for example
>   7119
>   We need the remainder of 119:4, but the remainder of 11:4, 112:4, 113:4, etc is 1 for even powers and 3 for odd powers; therefore, 7119 ends in the same digit as 73, that is, 3.

Following the same logic to 7^(6^21) we have 6^21 has unit digit equal to 6, because every number ending in 6 powered to any number is 6. So the second step is to solve 7^6 which is 9 right? 9 is the wrong answer, the true result is 1!
you can check it here [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%5E(6%5E21)+mod+10](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%5E(6%5E21)%20mod%2010)
Can anyone explain it?

Thanks

Comment: If you have a new problem, you can start another question.